# Site url token in view

Tags: 7, views, tokens

Are there any way to get site's base URL value in a token within view to use in its header and field(s).

My local developments is on drupal installation in a sub-directory while on server it is on a domain.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `global $base_url;` if you are using the PHP filter.

Answer (score 1):

You may use https://www.drupal.org/project/views_base_url

1. Add field Global: Base url
2. Hide it
3. Use token [base_url] D7 {{ base_url }} D8

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to get a token with the base URL but if you are rewriting links, etc. you can start with a slash like `href="/mydirectory/mypage` and Drupal will automatically add the base URL.

Comment: Starting with slash does not produce correct link in my local installation on subdirectory.

Comment: You may have better luck with the Pathologic module: http://drupal.org/project/pathologic/

Answer (score 0):

In No results behavior I have selected Global: Unfiltered text, and

```
< a href = "/search-landing-sell-property-type"> Click here </a>
```

results in the correct path to the page.

Comment: Does it work if you are running Drupal in a subdirectory? (e.g. `http://www.mydomain.com/drupal/…`)

Comment: Yes. In my case I have Drupal running in a subdirectory.